# α-path on Euclidean graphs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry

Consider the following problem:

- Suppose we are given a G=(*V*, *E*) Euclidean Graph in the plane and a real α > 0. For simplicity assume, there exists only one path whose summation of weights over all edges is equal to α. Give a polynomial decider to report such a α-path in *G* if exists.

  1. In spite of the fact that there are several experimental results (heuristic algorithm) for this problem I know there are several randomized algorithms have been given by people using color-coding in running times *O*(2<sup>*k*</sup>. Poly(n)) [Williams] and *O*((1.625)<sup>k</sup>.poly(*n*)) [Abbasi et al.], etc. For the case that graph is *Unweighted*, *Non-geometric* and integer *k* is considered as the number of vertices on the target path. The question is, is there any approximation algorithm for either on Euclidean or general graph or not? ( I know α or *k* can be large to extract the longest path, but here the length of longest path is given and might not be as hard as longest path problem).
  2. I am trying to come up with a preliminary solution for the Euclidean case using a hierarchical structure like quadtree or something to store the length of each subpath hierarchically into some higher level node(s) of the tree. Finding K=*O*(log φ) nodes in the tree that gives us c.α-path or some *c*, can tell us about the existence of a path on original graph. Can anyone give me some feedback about this approach? Or do I need using another different data structure? Any comment in regard to this problem is appreciated!